# Problems with creatWriteStream for .js

Tags: javascript, node.js, filestream, telegram-bot, ibm-watson

i have a problem with the fs.createWriteStream in javascript:

I'm trying to build a telegramBot with Watson Services (speech to text, translation, text to speech) that takes a voice message in input, translate it in text, send the text to the bot as message; Then the text will be translated in Italian, the translation will be sent as message to the bot; in the end, the translation will be passed as input for the text to speech and will be transformed in a file audio .ogg that will be sent to the bot. For the first two steps nothing wrong, but when i have to send the audio file to the bot, here come problems.

Below the part of code that imo has the problem:

```
text_to_speech.synthesize(params1).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('hello.ogg'));
      bot.sendVoice(chatId, 'hello.ogg', {
      disable_notification: true,
      reply_to_message_id: msg.message_id
     })
```

THe console says:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: 400 {"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: File must be non-empty"}
```

But the file is in the direcotry and contains effectively the audio that i expect.

I've even tried with the .on() method with the 'finish' event for the fileStream that i create but this didnt help. I use the "node-telegram-bot-api" for bot's API.

Thank you for the help

UPDATE

Thank you very much for the answer. Didnt think baout that solution. I've implemented your suggestion and the result is:

```
bot.sendVoice(chatId, text_to_speech.synthesize(params1), {
        disable_notification: true,
        reply_to_message_id: msg.message_id
      }).then(function(promise){console.log(promise)})
```

No error occurs in the process while the app is running, but nothing is sent to the bot. Other tips? (SOrry for my noobness, but i'm new to javascript)

UP!

Comment: According to the telegram module API, it can also accept a stream for the `voice` parameter, so why not just pass the stream instead of writing it to a file first? For example: `bot.sendVoice(chatId, text_to_speech.synthesize(params1), { ... });`. You will also want to correctly handle the Promise returned by `sendVoice()`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to send the file using multipart/form-data use  multer,busboy or restler module

> npm install [restler](https://github.com/danwrong/restler)